# static block of links, how to set an active class

Tags: jquery, css, magento

On my category listing pages i have a static block on my left menu with two links:

1) The category listing page link
2) CMS page of details.

The CMS page of details calls the exact same static block on it's left menu too.

My question:

How can Magento know in the static block of links that it is on the listing page or the cms page, and add a class of "active" to the link so we can change the CSS styling for the "active" page that is being viewed?

I'm open to a different approach then I currently have setup if that makes it more manageable.

Thanks!

EDIT 1

Link block (grc_sidebar_links)

```
<div class="arrow"><a href="/category/a.html">Category A</a></div>
<div class="arrow"><a href="/cata-specs">Specs and Pricing</a></div>
```

Sidebar block's html (grc_sidebar_spec_summary):

```
<div class="sidebar_top">{{block type="cms/block" block_id="grc_sidebar_links"}}</div>
```

And then in the category i have the following layout update for the page:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="cms/block" name="block_sidebar_top" before="-">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>grc_sidebar_spec_summary</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

And then in the CMS page i have the following layout update:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="cms/block" name="block_sidebar_top">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>grc_sidebar_spec_summary</block_id></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Please post some code to look at

Answer (score 1):

In general you should generate the link list by a block class. For get an idea of that take a look at *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml* and the corresponding block class.

In the app/../default/layout/catalog.xml you find this entry:

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

Inside the block node the block class is defined and the template file path. The type attribute tells Magento where to find the block class. So *catalog/navigation* points to *app/code/core/Mage/catalog/Block/Navigation.php*

The getCurrentChildCategories method generates an array of all child category links and also defines the active link.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you very much for some info!  that helps me keep on going.